# При открытии файла нулевого размера boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source бросает исключение. Что с этим можно сделать?

Tags: c++, boost, файловый-ввод-вывод, mapping

Есть файл (текстовый). Пытаюсь его открыть, при помощи boost iostreams. Если файл содержит текст (хотя бы 1 символ) - открывается, без ошибок и без нареканий. Но если он пуст (т.е. без символов, `std::filesystem::file_size(...) == 0`), вылетает исключение "iostream stream error", "failed create mapping", следующего содержания:

> ***RU:*** "Том для открытого файла был изменен извне, поэтому работа с этим
> файлом невозможна."
>  ***EN:*** "The volume of a file has been externally
> altered and open file is not longer valid."

Код примерно такой (суть идеи):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <filesystem>
   #include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
   #include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

   using std::filesystem::path;
   using boost::iostreams::mapped_file;
   using boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params;
   using boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source;
   using boost::iostreams::stream;

   void open_file(stream<mapped_file_source>& stream, std::filesystem::path){
        if (stream.is_open())return;    

        const auto generic_string_path = path.generic_string();

        mapped_file_params params(generic_string_path);
        params.flags = mapped_file::mapmode::readonly;
        params.length = file_size(path);
    
        printf("Opening file %s\n", generic_string_path.c_str());
    
        mapped_file_source file_source(params);

        printf("Trying open\n");
    
        (!(path.has_extension() && (path.extension() == "txt"))) ?
            stream.open(file_source, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary) :
            stream.open(file_source, std::ios::in);
    
        printf("File %s is opened\n", generic_string_path.c_str());
   }
```

Исключение вылетает при создании `mapped_file_source`.

Для сравнения, в точно такой же ситуации (при `std::filesystem::file_size(...) == 0`), `std::ifstream` ведёт себя приличнее: поток корректно открывается, пусть и ничего не содержит. Но `stream<mapped_file_source>` - увы, из-за того, что `mapped_file_source` бросает это исключение, не может быть открыт.

**Ключевой вопрос:** **что с этим можно сделать, учитывая, что от `stream<mapped_file_source>` хотелось бы поведения схожего с `ifstream`, с тем различием, что `stream<mapped_file_source>` использует отображение файла в память?**

P.S> Идеальным вариантом, было бы не просто конструировать поток для отображаемого в память файла, но и иметь возможность редактировать и заменять файл "на горячую" (что-нибудь с boost interprocess) - это при открытом в программе потоке - без вызова `stream.close()` (это, скорее, из разряда хотелок, прямого отношения к вопросу не имеет - скорее как пояснение контекста: у меня всё шаманство крутится в отдельном потоке, проверяет состояние загруженных данных [из файлов] и, если какой-либо файл обновился, обновляет соответствующие данные в памяти из этого файла - перезагружает их из него). **Но главное, повторюсь, избежать исключения при открытии пустого файла - если это вообще возможно.**

Comment: 1) Нельзя мапить пустой файл куда-либо. У него обязательно должен быть размер отличный от нуля (можете man посмотреть https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html, английским по белому написано must be greater than zero) 
2) Ерунда детектед. Если файл правильно смаплен на память, изменения в нем обновляются в памяти автоматически, не нужно ничего перезагружать.

Comment: @gbg "Если файл правильно смаплен на память, изменения в нем обновляются в памяти автоматически, не нужно ничего перезагружать" - видимо он у меня неправильно смаплен: открываю блокнотом файл (поток на мапленный файл в проге открыт), пытаюсь отредактировать, Ctrl+s - fail: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, т.к. этот файл занят другим процессом". Т.е., если я не закрываю поток со смапленным файлом, то не могу его редактировать сторонней прогой (блокнотом, например). Поэтому, приходится его закрывать, чтобы сторонней прогой его отредактировать, а потом, переоткрыть при изменениях.

Comment: ну да, файл смаплен неправильно. Нужно разрешать параллельные операции - FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ при вызове CreateFile.

Конечно, можно повесить уведомление на изменение каталога, и потом перемапливать файл, но это плохая идея, если вы сооружаете межпроцессную коммуникацию.